Error occurred during creation of Azure DevOps Service hook: TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: f75c09f1-a86e-4f14-a221-7cf17e9ab4cb
I trying to Create Service Hook in Azure DevOps for Jenkins then it showing error as

TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: f75c09f1-a86e-4f14-a221-7cf17e9ab4cb.

And in network response showing:
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: f75c09f1-a86e-4f14-a221-7cf17e9ab4cb.",
    "typeName": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssServiceException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common",
    "typeKey": "VssServiceException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 3000
}

I'm not able to create service hook in Azure DevOps due to this error.
I have tried from different Jenkins also but it throwing same error. Please share some solutions.

Glad to see you in Stack overflow. The activity id is an internal error id, which cannot be checked in public. It looks like a community-specific query. Please refer to Stack overflow how to ask, thanks.

In addition, please follow the doc Create a service hook for Azure DevOps with Jenkins for a check, make sure all check are green  before you create the service hook.
